# Why would my array on my MVC Controller be null on Ajax Postback

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my array:

```
{latlng: [{lat: 41.9841092242239, lng: -87.6459866168}, {lat: 41.948650308164744, lng: -87.64431828280067}, {lat: 41.94833112697515, lng: -87.644017875391}]
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
  var postedData = JSON.stringify({
                latlng: boundaries
            });

            alert("here are your boundaries so far : " + postedData);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Communities/UpdateBoundaries',
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: postedData,
                datatype: "json",
                success: function () {
                    console.log('success!!');
                }
            });
        }
```

and here is my controller: where boundaries is my incoming array of latlng, but it is coming in null.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateBoundaries(List<latLng> boundaries)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var postedData = JSON.stringify({latlng: boundaries});
```

to

```
var postedData = JSON.stringify(boundaries);
```

This is because the action parameter is an array. **If** it were a type that contained an array property with property name `latlng` then you pass it in the same manner you did in your existing code.

Comment: i received an error on JSON.Stringify not a function

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel - lowercase s in stringify. javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel - you are running this in a browser right? Try re-typing it as maybe it was not copied from the browser correctly: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know what I did wrong before, but this time it worked.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel - good deal! If this solves your problem please consider marking it as the answer.